# embedding qt4 application with gtk application on linux

Tags: python, linux, qt4, pygtk

I am developing a pygtk based application. In next development, I want to embed QT based visualization application in main GTK application.

I am using python-2.5.5+ and pygtk on LINUX platform.

Is there any way to do it??

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. Why don't you use Qt in the first place?

Comment: Main pygtk application is already ready and working.We want to add 3d visualization using VTK, which requires qt4.

Comment: In that case... Check this out: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2005-August/msg00173.html

Comment: If you ultimately want to display VTK in a GTK window, I suggest you rephrase the question to make this clear. This may actually not involve Qt at all, since VTK supports a variety of backends (such as OpenGL)

Comment: Here is a project that appears to be doing exactly what you want: http://visu.sourceforge.net/about.en.html